# Zip code validation for website

Tags: javascript

I am helping my dad out with a website for his local flower shop and he wants to have a search bar where people can put in their zip code and confirm that he delivers to their address. I need help getting the code to work.

I want users to be redirected to a another site if their zip code is in the delivery area, and I want an error message to be displayed for zip codes outside of the delivery area.

This is what I have so far:

```html
<input type="text" id="zipCode">
<input type="button" onclick="checkZipcode()">
```

```js
var zipcodes = [12345,54321];

function checkZipcode(){
  var i, validCode = false;
  for(i=0;i<zipcodes.length;i++){
    if (zipcodes[i] == document.getElementById('zipCode').value)
      validCode = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you make me delete all my answers today...

Comment: @michael: Wasn't trying to! :-) And it's great that you're trying to help people! In this case, I figured you'd either leave it or edit it, both of which were perfectly viable options.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know :-) Paul's answer is good enough though...

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I am trying to run it in code pen but I am getting errors. This all goes in the JS section right? Please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track. We can simplify the `validCode` logic a bit:

```
var zip = document.getElementById('zipCode').value;
var validCode = zipcodes.indexOf(zip) >= 0;
```

Then react accordingly:

```
if (validCode)
  document.location.href = 'http://example.com/some/other/place';
else
  alert("Sorry, we can't deliver to " + zip);  
  // or show a previously-hidden <div>, etc.
```